# Set browserresolution with WebClient in c#

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

I am trying to make a webbot which should look for the site like a legit browser.

at the moment i am stuck with the browserresolution. The default resolution of webclient.DownloadString is 0x0 (or not set at all?) pixels.

how can I set the brwoserresolution to something else?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient httpClient = new WebClient();
    var result = httpClient.DownloadString("http://howbigismybrowser.com/");
    var Doc = new HtmlDocument();
    Doc.LoadHtml(result);
}
//result is 
//[...]
// <div id="counter">
//   <span class="num"></span>
//   <span id="divider"></span>
//   <span class="num"></span>
// </div>
//[...]
```

the result with chrome is

```
<div id="counter">
  <span class="num">1273</span>
  <span id="divider"></span>
  <span class="num">938</span>
</div>
```

appriciate any help

Comment: `WebClient` is not a `WebBrowser`. It doesn't have a `Window` to measure. It's asking to download a string. `var Doc = new HtmlDocument(); <= `Does it compile?

Comment: _should look [to] the site like a legit browser_ - look up "headless browser"

Comment: @Jimi this is from HtmlAgilityPack, frogot to mention it sorry.
HenkHolterman I am currently using Selenium but it is not the best way since i want to execute some action from multiple accounts and it would require a big amount of windows open.

Correct me if i am wrong but a website knows the resolution of your browser because you send it with the request. So it must be possible to make a request where you can set the data for the resolution (i mean it is also possible to set a useragent for example)

Comment: The scripts that are executed when the html page is loaded in the WebBrowser Window, have access to some properties of the Window. WebClient doesn't have a Window and doesn't execute scripts, of course.